# Formvalidation.io Bootstrap 5 label color

Tags: bootstrap-5, formvalidation.io

In bootstrap 4, when there field was valid/invalid, the label color had the same valid/invalid color of the input field. However. when using the Bootstrap 5 plugin, only the  input field changes color and the label does not.

Is there a way to retain the old way in which the label changed color too?